# How to access the BIOS in a Thinkpad X240?

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop

I bought a used Lenovo Thinkpad X240, with Windows 10 pre-installed. As I am planning on deleting Windows and using Ubuntu, I followed suggestions and updated the BIOS which is now version 2.36.

But I have a problem: I cannot get into the BIOS. During the Lenovo logo, there is no message to press Enter to get into the BIOS; and pressing F1, Fn+F1, F2 or F12 or Enter do not do anything, and Windows boots normally.

The only way i can get into the BIOS is from within Windows to go to Updates -> Restore -> Restart to manually tell Windows to reboot into BIOS. Then the "Press enter ..." message appears during the Lenovo logo, but as I want to delete Windows, this is not really a solution

So... how can I get into the BIOS?

Comment: use Advanced Startup.  Change the boot order, then format the disk, then install the os of your hcoice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hadn't realized that "Shut down" in Windows 10 actually means "Shut down and hybernate"... After a "hard" shut down by pressing Shift while clicking on "Shut down", Windows actually shuts down, and the "press enter ..." message appears and I can get into the BIOS...